# AdWhirl integration with MillennialMedia, symbol(s) not found

Tags: iphone, ios, adwhirl

i want to enable MM ad in my adwhirl. i did the same thing as other networks like inmobi, admob, mobclix etc, but with MM, i get this error:

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
  -[MMFileManager getMimeType:] in libMMSDK.a(MMFileManager.o)
  "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
  -[MMFileManager getMimeType:] in libMMSDK.a(MMFileManager.o)
  "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:
  -[MMFileManager getMimeType:] in libMMSDK.a(MMFileManager.o)
  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
  -[MMFileManager getMimeType:] in libMMSDK.a(MMFileManager.o)
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

i didn't changed the adwhirl adapters, just drag the MM sdk into the project. this never happened for my admob integration. 
plz help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the MobileCoreServices framework isn't included in your project. Include that framework and it should work.

Comment: works now, weird that MM requires more framework then other ad company. i guess EMEENE needs to update his tutorial now.

Answer (score 1):

Symbol not found can have the following causes:

- You did not add the code that contains the missing symbols like UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag
- You did not link your app with the library that provides these symbols

Check your target's "Link Binary with Libraries" section and make sure that whatever library is used for MM is added to the list.

> symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

This indicates that you're building for the iOS Simulator. It is possible that MM simply does not provide code that runs in iOS Simulator, only on devices. Try doing a device build.